# JavaScript handle bars not showing data

Tags: javascript, jquery, handlebars.js

I'm using handlebars to display a set of javascript arrays in an html.

The javascript arrays look like this

```
[{pid:"1mn0wZj6yN", id:"yUjCaVzZ3CcCdOj"},{pid:"uEG9LXUaZi", id:"0eamlmJAFd2Ltwd"}]
```

Make a jquery get request to get this array

```
$.get( "file.php", function( respo ) {
       var temmple = Handlebars.compile($('#template').html());
       $('#container').append(temmple(respo));      
  });
```

This is the handle bars template

```
 <script id="template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
          {{#each respo}}
          <p>{{id}}</p>
          {{/each}}
 </script>
```

The output be displayed in a div with an id called container, but the output doesn't show up and doesn't give any errors also. How can i fix this? thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
{{#each this}}
  <p>{{id}}</p>
{{/each}}
```

Is probably what you need, unless you had an object named respo inside the object you are passing to handlebars.

[example](http://jsbin.com/OYAMUCe/1/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: for some reason the values in your json are not delimited by commas, maybe that is your issue. i added an example to my answer :)

Comment: seems like the problem is having in the get request, it works outside get request, but not within the get request, there is no error within the get request. any way to fix this?

Comment: maybe its because you are trying to load json from a php file ಠ_ಠ